# Unable to get multiple notifications on same device with different device tokens

Tags: php, android, ios, codeigniter

I have to implement notification functionality in my project which is made in CodeIgniter.

Scenario is like, I have two apps in my device i.e. **driver** and **passenger** app. I have created a function in a controller file and trying to send notifications to both the apps. But I am getting the notification on only one driver app.

Below is my controller function. Please suggest me where I am committing mistake -

```
public function tripNotStartedCron() { 
        try {
            $allTripsdata = $this->trip->getAllTripsCron();
            echo "<pre>";print_r($allTripsdata);
            $allCancelTripsdata = $this->trip->getAllTripsCron(1);
            print_r($allCancelTripsdata); 

            // Send notification for trip notification after 30 min
            foreach ($allTripsdata as $tripsData) {
                /* Time calculation */
                $buggyTimeZones = array('19800' => 'Asia/Calcutta');
                if (array_key_exists($tripsData['timezone'], $buggyTimeZones)) {
                    $pickUpLocationTimeZone = $buggyTimeZones[$tripsData['timezone']];
                } else {
                    $pickUpLocationTimeZone = timezone_name_from_abbr('', $tripsData['timezone'], 0);
                }

                $date = new DateTime('NOW', new DateTimeZone($pickUpLocationTimeZone)); 
                $tripsData['pickupdatetime'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($tripsData['pickupdatetime'] . ' +' . CONFIRMED_CANCELLED_TRIP . ' minutes'));
                $tripDateTime = new DateTime($tripsData['pickupdatetime'], new DateTimeZone($pickUpLocationTimeZone)); 
                /* End time calculation */
                $driverId = $tripsData['fkdriverid'];
                $rideId = $tripsData['rideid'];
                $asap = $tripsData['is_pickup_as_soon'];
                $tripStatusId = TRIP_STATUS_DRIVERCONFIRMED;
                //$message = 'You have a trip that was scheduled to start more than ' . CONFIRMED_CANCELLED_TRIP . ' minutes ago, if you do not start it within ' . DRIVER_TRIP_CANCELLED_SECOND_WARING . ' minutes it will be automatically cancelled.';
                $message = 'You have a trip that was scheduled to start more than 1 hour ago, if you do not start it within ' . DRIVER_TRIP_CANCELLED_SECOND_WARING . ' minutes it will be automatically cancelled.';
                //echo date($date->format('U'))."----------".date($tripDateTime->format('U'));
                if ($date->format('U') > $tripDateTime->format('U')) { 
                    if ($driverId > 0) {
                        /*                         * ** Send push notificaion on ios *** */
                        $iosDeviceDetailArr = $this->profile->getIosNotificationStatus($driverId, DRIVER_ROLE, IOS);
                        $tripCompleteDetail = $this->trip->getOrderDetailForARide($rideId);
                        $driverDetails = $this->profile->getDriverDetails($driverId);
                        $driverBUserId = $driverDetails[0]->id ? $driverDetails[0]->id : 0;
                        $driverCurrentUserId = $driverId;
                        $driverCurrentRoleId = DRIVER_ROLE;
                        $additionalDetail = array();
                        if (!empty($driverBUserId)) {
                            $additionalDetail = array('bUserId' => $driverBUserId, 'currentUserId' => $driverCurrentUserId, 'currentRoleId' => $driverCurrentRoleId);
                        }
                        /* store notification detail in db start */
                        $dataDictionary = array(
                            'alert' => $message,
                            'ondemand' => $asap,
                            'ridedetail' => $tripCompleteDetail,
                            'rideid' => $rideId,
                            'type' => "trip_cancel_reminder",
                            'userdetail' => $additionalDetail
                        );
                        $dataToSave = array(
                            'buserid' => $additionalDetail['bUserId'],
                            'currentuserid' => $additionalDetail['currentUserId'],
                            'currentroleid' => $additionalDetail['currentRoleId'],
                            'datadictionary' => json_encode($dataDictionary),
                            'rideid' => $rideId,
                            'notificationlabel' => 'Trip Scheduling Alert',
                            'createddate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                            'modifydate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                        );
                        $notificationId = $this->common->saveDetails(TBL_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS, $dataToSave);
                        if ($notificationId) {
                            updateNotificationStatus(array('currentuserid' => $additionalDetail['currentUserId'], 'rideid' => $rideId, 'notificationid !=' => $notificationId), 'trip_cancel_reminder');
                        }
                        $tripCompleteDetail[0]['notificationId'] = (isset($notificationId) && $notificationId) ? $notificationId : 0;
                        /* store notification detail in db start */
                        $res = member_notification_ios($iosDeviceDetailArr, $message, $rideId, $asap, $tripCompleteDetail, $additionalDetail, 'trip_cancel_reminder'); 

                        /*                         * ** Send push notificaion on antroid device *** */
                        $androidDeviceDetailArr = $this->profile->getIosNotificationStatus($driverId, DRIVER_ROLE, ANTROID);
                        if (is_array($androidDeviceDetailArr) && count($androidDeviceDetailArr) > 0)
                            foreach ($androidDeviceDetailArr as $deviceDetail) {
                                /*                                 * ** Code for send push notification *** */
                                $deviceToken = isset($deviceDetail['devicetoken']) ? $deviceDetail['devicetoken'] : '';
                                $deviceToken = get_device_token($deviceToken);
                                if (isset($deviceToken) && !empty($deviceToken))
                                    $androidRes = member_notification_antroid($deviceDetail['devicetoken'], $message, $rideId, $asap, $tripCompleteDetail, $additionalDetail, 'trip_cancel_reminder');
                            }


                        /* Update notification status in TBL_TRIPS_ASSIGNEDDRIVER table */
                        $data = array('notificationflag' => 1);
                        $condition = array('fkdriverid' => $driverId, 'rideid' => $rideId, 'tripstatusid' => $tripStatusId);
                        $updateResult = $this->common->saveDetails(TBL_TRIPS_ASSIGNEDDRIVER, $data, $condition);
                        /*                         * ** End of code for push notification *** */
                    }
                }
            }

            // Send notification for trip cancelation after 35 min            
            foreach ($allCancelTripsdata as $canceltripsData) { 
                /* Time calculation */
                $buggyTimeZones = array('19800' => 'Asia/Calcutta');
                if (array_key_exists($canceltripsData['timezone'], $buggyTimeZones)) {
                    $pickUpLocationTimeZone = $buggyTimeZones[$canceltripsData['timezone']];
                } else {
                    $pickUpLocationTimeZone = timezone_name_from_abbr('', $canceltripsData['timezone'], 0);
                }
                $date = new DateTime('NOW', new DateTimeZone($pickUpLocationTimeZone));
                $canceltripsData['pickupdatetime'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($canceltripsData['pickupdatetime'] . ' +' . CONFIRMED_CANCELLED_TRIP_FINAL . ' minutes'));
                $tripDateTime = new DateTime($canceltripsData['pickupdatetime'], new DateTimeZone($pickUpLocationTimeZone));
                $driverId = $canceltripsData['fkdriverid'];
                $rideId = $canceltripsData['rideid'];
                $asap = $canceltripsData['is_pickup_as_soon'];
                $tripStatusId = TRIP_STATUS_DRIVERCONFIRMED;
                //$message = 'Your trip has been cancelled because it was never started.';
                $messagePassenger = 'Your trip has been cancelled because the driver did not show up to the location.';
                $messageDriver = 'Your trip has been cancelled because you did not show up to the location.';
                if ($date->format('U') > $tripDateTime->format('U')) {
                    if ($driverId > 0) {
                        /** ** Send push notificaion on ios *** */
                        $tripCompleteDetail = $this->trip->getOrderDetailForARide($rideId);
                        $iosDeviceDetailArrDriver = $this->profile->getIosNotificationStatus($driverId, DRIVER_ROLE, IOS);


                        //echo "<pre>";print_r($iosDeviceDetailArr);die(' ll');

                        $driverDetails = $this->profile->getDriverDetails($driverId);
                        $driverBUserId = $driverDetails[0]->id ? $driverDetails[0]->id : 0;
                        $driverCurrentUserId = $driverId;
                        $driverCurrentRoleId = DRIVER_ROLE;
                        $additionalDetailDriver = array();
                        $additionalDetailPassenger = array();

                        if (!empty($driverBUserId)) {
                            $additionalDetailDriver = array('bUserId' => $driverBUserId, 'currentUserId' => $driverCurrentUserId, 'currentRoleId' => $driverCurrentRoleId);
                        }

                        /* store notification detail in db start */
                        $dataDictionaryDriver = array(
                            'alert' => $messageDriver,
                            'ondemand' => $asap,
                            'ridedetail' => $tripCompleteDetail,
                            'rideid' => $rideId,
                            'type' => "trip_cancel_notification_driver",
                            'userdetail' => $additionalDetailDriver
                        );

                        $dataToSaveDriver = array(
                            'buserid' => $additionalDetailDriver['bUserId'],
                            'currentuserid' => $additionalDetailDriver['currentUserId'],
                            'currentroleid' => $additionalDetailDriver['currentRoleId'],
                            'datadictionary' => json_encode($dataDictionaryDriver),
                            'rideid' => $rideId,
                            'notificationlabel' => 'Trip Cancelled',
                            'forlisting' => 0,
                            'createddate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                            'modifydate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                        );

                        $notificationIdDriver = $this->common->saveDetails(TBL_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS, $dataToSaveDriver);

                        if ($notificationIdDriver) {
                            updateNotificationStatus(array('currentuserid' => $additionalDetailDriver['currentUserId'], 'rideid' => $rideId, 'notificationid !=' => $notificationIdDriver), 'trip_cancel_notification_driver');
                        }

                        $tripCompleteDetail[0]['notificationId'] = (isset($notificationIdDriver) && $notificationIdDriver) ? $notificationIdDriver : 0;


                        /* store notification detail in db start */
                        $res = member_notification_ios($iosDeviceDetailArrDriver, $messageDriver, $rideId, $asap, $tripCompleteDetail, $additionalDetailDriver, 'trip_cancel_notification_driver'); 
                        $androidDeviceDetailArrDriver = $this->profile->getIosNotificationStatus($driverId, DRIVER_ROLE, ANTROID);
                        if (is_array($androidDeviceDetailArrDriver) && count($androidDeviceDetailArrDriver) > 0) {
                            foreach ($androidDeviceDetailArrDriver as $deviceDetail) {
                                /*                                 * ** Code for send push notification *** */
                                $deviceToken = isset($deviceDetail['devicetoken']) ? $deviceDetail['devicetoken'] : '';
                                $deviceToken = get_device_token($deviceToken);
                                if (isset($deviceToken) && !empty($deviceToken))
                                    $androidRes = member_notification_antroid($deviceDetail['devicetoken'], $messageDriver, $rideId, $asap, $tripCompleteDetail, $additionalDetailDriver, 'trip_cancel_notification_driver');
                            }
                        }
                        /*********************************************************/
                        $iosDeviceDetailArrPassenger = $this->profile->getIosNotificationStatus($tripCompleteDetail[0]['currentuserid'], USER_ROLE, IOS);
                        $userRecord = $this->common->getData(TBL_USE_AS, array('use_driverfy_as' => $tripCompleteDetail[0]['currentuserid']), 'array', 'userid', 'rows');
                        if (!empty($userRecord)) {
                            $additionalDetailPassenger = array('bUserId' => $userRecord[0]['userid'], 'currentUserId' => $tripCompleteDetail[0]['currentuserid'], 'currentRoleId' => USER_ROLE);
                        }
                        $dataDictionaryPassenger = array(
                            'alert' => $messagePassenger,
                            'ondemand' => $asap,
                            'ridedetail' => $tripCompleteDetail,
                            'rideid' => $rideId,
                            'type' => "trip_cancel_notification_passenger",
                            'userdetail' => $additionalDetailPassenger
                        );
                        $dataToSavePassenger = array(
                            'buserid' => $additionalDetailPassenger['bUserId'],
                            'currentuserid' => $additionalDetailPassenger['currentUserId'],
                            'currentroleid' => $additionalDetailPassenger['currentRoleId'],
                            'datadictionary' => json_encode($dataDictionaryPassenger),
                            'rideid' => $rideId,
                            'notificationlabel' => 'Trip Cancelled',
                            'forlisting' => 0,
                            'createddate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                            'modifydate' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                        );
                        $notificationIdPassenger = $this->common->saveDetails(TBL_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS, $dataToSavePassenger);
                        if ($notificationIdPassenger) {
                            updateNotificationStatus(array('currentuserid' => $additionalDetailPassenger['currentUserId'], 'rideid' => $rideId, 'notificationid !=' => $notificationIdPassenger), 'trip_cancel_notification_passenger');
                        }
                        $tripCompleteDetail[0]['notificationId'] = (isset($notificationIdPassenger) && $notificationIdPassenger) ? $notificationIdPassenger : 0;

                        /* store notification detail in db start */

                        $res = member_notification_ios($iosDeviceDetailArrPassenger, $messagePassenger, $rideId, $asap, $tripCompleteDetail, $additionalDetailPassenger, 'trip_cancel_notification_passenger', '', USER_ROLE); 
                        die("tt");

                        /** ** Send push notificaion on antroid device *** */

                        $androidDeviceDetailArrPassenger = $this->profile->getIosNotificationStatus($tripCompleteDetail[0]['currentuserid'], USER_ROLE, ANTROID);


                        if (is_array($androidDeviceDetailArrPassenger) && count($androidDeviceDetailArrPassenger) > 0) {
                            foreach ($androidDeviceDetailArrPassenger as $deviceDetail) {
                                /*                                 * ** Code for send push notification *** */
                                $deviceToken = isset($deviceDetail['devicetoken']) ? $deviceDetail['devicetoken'] : '';
                                $deviceToken = get_device_token($deviceToken);
                                if (isset($deviceToken) && !empty($deviceToken))
                                    $androidRes = member_notification_antroid($deviceDetail['devicetoken'], $messagePassenger, $rideId, $asap, $tripCompleteDetail, $additionalDetailPassenger, 'trip_cancel_notification_passenger');
                            }
                        }
                        /*                         * ** End Send push notificaion on antroid device *** */

                        /* Update notification status in TBL_TRIPS_ASSIGNEDDRIVER table */
                        $cancelData = array('tripstatusid' => TRIP_STATUS_CANCEL_RUN);
                        $conditionCancel = array('fkdriverid' => $driverId, 'rideid' => $rideId, 'tripstatusid' => $tripStatusId);
                        $updateResult = $this->common->saveDetails(TBL_TRIPS_ASSIGNEDDRIVER, $cancelData, $conditionCancel);
                        /*                         * ** End of code for push notification *** */

                        /* Code for void authorized amount of cancel trip */

                        $orderResultedData = $this->common->getData(TBL_RS_ORDER, array('bookingid' => $canceltripsData['bookingid']), 'array', 'orderid');
                        //echo 'orderId=>'.$orderResultedData['orderid']; echo "<br/>";
                        $tripAuthorizationDetails = $this->common->getRowDetails(TBL_RS_ORDER_AUTHORIZATION, array('orderid' => $orderResultedData['orderid'], 'authorization_status' => 'hold', 'is_edit_charge' => 0, 'is_cancel_charge' => 0), '', 1);
                        //print_r($tripAuthorizationDetails);
                        if (count($tripAuthorizationDetails) > 0) {
                            foreach ($tripAuthorizationDetails as $key => $value) {
                                $brainTreeAuthorizationId = base64_decode($value['braintree_authorization_id']);
                                $orderAuthorizationId = $value['id'];
                                /* Here we will void all amount and maintain records in tables for future */
                                $this->load->library("braintreelib");
                                $rsltVoidSucc = $this->braintreelib->voidTransactionCustomer($brainTreeAuthorizationId);
                                if ($rsltVoidSucc->success) {
                                    /* Insert records in escrow details table */
                                    $tableName = TBL_ORDER_ESCROW_DETAIL;
                                    $condition = array();
                                    $dataToSave = array(
                                        'escrow_status' => VOID_ALL_AMOUNT,
                                        'order_id' => $orderResultedData['orderid'],
                                        'final_trip_amount' => 0,
                                        'created_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                                        'braintree_escrow_id' => $brainTreeAuthorizationId,
                                        'order_authorization_id' => $orderAuthorizationId
                                    );
                                    $insertData = $this->common->saveDetails($tableName, $dataToSave, $condition);
                                    if ($insertData) {
                                        $updateData = $this->common->saveDetails(TBL_RS_ORDER_AUTHORIZATION, array('authorization_status' => 'amount_void'), array('id' => $value['id']));
                                    } else {
                                        $this->data['status'] = faLSE;
                                        $this->data['data'] = '';
                                        $this->data['errorMessages'] = 'Your trip is cancel, but amount is not refund. Please contact to admin.';
                                    }
                                    /* End */
                                } else {
                                    $errorFound = '';
                                    foreach ($rsltVoidSucc->errors->deepAll() as $error) {
                                        echo $errorFound = $error->message;
                                    }
                                    die();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        /* End code for void authorized amount of cancel trip */
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage() . "<br>" . $e->getFile() . "<br>" . $e->getLine();
        }
    }
```